# writing a code in C with strcmp that create dictionary

Tags: arrays, c, dictionary, strcmp

In my homework I was asked to write a code that receives from the user 10 strings in size 10 Into an array of strings that will act like a dictionary.
for example if the user enter *bbb* , *ccc* , *abc* , *acb*. the code will print

```text
abc
acb
bbb
ccc
```

In our last lesson we learned about strcmp so i thought to use it here. This is what I got, I know it's worng but I have no idea what else to do so I hope someone here can help me.
The code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {

    int i;
    int j;
    int index;
    char a_word[10][10];
    printf("Enter string:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s[^\n]", a_word[i]);
    }
    i = 0;
    j = 1;
    while (index<10)
    {
        if (strcmp(a_word[i], a_word[j]) == -1)
        {
            j++;
            index++;
        }
        else if (strcmp(a_word[j], a_word[i]) <= 0)
        {
            i++;
            index++;
        }
    }
    if (strcmp(a_word[i], a_word[j]) <= 0)
    {
        printf("%s",&a_word[i]);
    }
    else if (strcmp(a_word[j], a_word[i]) <= 0)
    {
        printf("%s",&a_word[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I know it's worng" Why? What are the symptoms?

Comment: `strcmp(a_word[i], a_word[j]) == -1` Read the docu of strcmp again. Expecting a return value of -1.

Comment: Are you trying to sort the words alphabetically?